# Proof using exhaustion $n^4 - 1$ is divisible by $5$ where $n$ is not divisible by $5$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The title pretty much states it.
Proof using exhaustion $n^4 - 1$ is divisible by $5$ where $n$ is not divisible by $5$.

Can anyone give me a hint how to approach this?
Do I need to consider separate case where n is odd and when n is even?

Solution: use division algorithm

Comment: Just consider two cases: $n=5k\pm 1$ and $n=5k\pm 2$. Substitute and expand.

Answer (score 7):

We have $n^4-1 = (n-1)(n+1)(n^2+1)$. Hence, if
\begin{align}
n \equiv 5k+1 & \implies 5 \vert n-1  & \implies 5 \vert n^4-1\\
n \equiv 5k-1 & \implies 5 \vert n+1 & \implies 5 \vert n^4-1\\
n \equiv 5k\pm2 & \implies 5 \vert n^2+1 & \implies 5 \vert n^4-1
\end{align}

Comment: i finally get it thanks man!

Answer (score 3):

By the division algorithm, any $n \in \mathbb Z$ can be expressed uniquely in the form:
$$
n = 5q + r
$$
where $q \in \mathbb Z$ and $r \in \{0,1,2,3,4\}$. If $r = 0$, then $n$ is divisible by $5$. So to complete your proof by exhaustion, it suffices to split into four cases (one for each possible nonzero remainder) and show that each case leads to $n^4 - 1$ being divisible by $5$.

Comment: ahhh I didn't realise that! Thank you. Almost forget about this, I should've thought about it a little longer before running to the internet asking for help. Anyway, thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $$n^{4}-1= (n^{2}+1)(n-1)(n+1) = [(n^{2}-4) +5](n-1)(n+1) = (n-2)(n-1)(n+1)(n+2) + 5(n-1)(n+1)$$

Clearly the second term is divisible by 5. Can you see why the first must be aswell, given that $\gcd(5,n)=1$?